# TinyMCE - default style

Tags: css, styles, tinymce, default

I would like to know how to select a default class of a CSS for applying it in tinymce, following this example :

```
 tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    editor_selector : "textarea_number_1",
    content_css : "css/custom_content.css",

    default-style : 'NameOfMyClass'; <- here is my problem ! Please, help me :)
}
```

I have 3 texteareas in my page, only one CSS file, but I want to select a different default class for each textarea.

This is only for the display in the TinyMCE editor, in the php post treatment I delete the 'p' tags from the retrieved content.

Thanks for any suggestion, and if I'm not clear enough, I can explain any point of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is to use different configurations: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/multiple_configs.php

The other way is to have one default object holding settings for all editors and before you use `tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'your_textarea_id');` you merge the default object with another object holding the additional settings. See for more info also [Tinymce how to reduce options for multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565212/tinymce-how-to-reduce-options-for-multiple-instances)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to affect different style in each editor of the page, using a css class.

Comment: this is possible, you can set a css class in each seperate configuration using the tinymce config param content_css

Comment: OK, but that means I've to call a different css file for each editor of a same page, no ? and in each define the p tag aspect, right ?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, i will not solve my problem as easly i hoped.

Comment: you can create a tinymce fiddle and i can correct it so that you will get what you need. just insert several textareas with unique ids and show what you tried so far: fiddle.tinymce.com

Comment: Thanks for the cleaned code !
This is what I would like to do :
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/vMcaab/7
with the css definition in the editor setup ...

Comment: see http://fiddle.tinymce.com/vMcaab/8 . now you need to set a css file containing your styles using the content_css setting. i wrote some things into a comment in the fiddle

Comment: Great ! many thanks for your help :)
However, the result is not quite the one I was expecting. I think I reached one of the limitations of TinyMCE. Later, I should modify the code editor to make exactly what I want, because even Moxiecode not give me a solution.